# How to edit a dropdown scrollbar with CSS?

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I am working on a dropdown menu and am having difficulty adjusting the scrollbar when the menu is clicked. I have tried targeting everything but I can't seem to get it to work. (I set the width to 20px so I can easily tell if it has adjusted the scrollbar). I am using Google Chrome. I'm sure it's a simple fix that I'm missing. Thank you for your time.

```css
select::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <select class="dropdown">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
    <option value="11">Eleven</option>
    <option value="12">Twelve</option>
    <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
    <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
    <option value="15">Fifteen</option>
    <option value="16">Sixteen</option>
    <option value="17">Seventeen</option>
    <option value="18">Eighteen</option>
    <option value="19">Nineteen</option>
    <option value="20">Twenty</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you will be netter off by just creating a js solution, then trying to get every Browser behave

Comment: What are you trying to change on the scrollbar?

Comment: I would like to make it smaller and set the background as #cccccc

Comment: You Have to use some another jquery library to make your things possible. for example Select2 js

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but I made a jsfiddle of what I think you're asking. It's a really simple thing, though, so I don't know if you wanted this... https://jsfiddle.net/fb3ccaov/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would add a size to the select, then the bar shows up and your css should work. You just need to pick how many you want to show up by default.

Also check out this page for more options https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

```
<div class = "dropdown-container">
  <select class="dropdown" size="5">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
    <option value="11">Eleven</option>
    <option value="12">Twelve</option>
    <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
    <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
    <option value="15">Fifteen</option>
    <option value="16">Sixteen</option>
    <option value="17">Seventeen</option>
    <option value="18">Eighteen</option>
    <option value="19">Nineteen</option>
    <option value="20">Twenty</option>
  </select>
</div>

select::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  background-color:#cccccc;
 }
```